Windows - Search for folders/files containing "~" in their names
there are few questions and answer about different wildcards, but cant find any about escape character, or other way to find files/dir starting, or containing "~" character.
~=~* or
~=~~*
does not work..

if you don't object to a third party, lightweight program, Everything from voidtools will do the trick.
The program searches only filenames, will not search content and is rather fast as a result.
I've just run a test on my machine and any combination of characters with the tilde works as one would expect.

There is a command line download as well, near the bottom of the linked page.

Images from linked site.
I was also able to "install" the command line program and it passes the tilde test. With command line available, one can pipe or redirect the output, of course.

Hi, thanks for your answer, just hopping windows built-in search is able to do that as well. I would use this app as a backup solution.
